# System Exit if dialog textfield matches private text field

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have implemented a dialog box, I also get the text field as a string. Now the problem I have is that I want to compare the text input to a String and exit the app if the text on the dialog box matches either a string under (R.strings.stringname) or either a private String variable.

I have implemented this code but it does not seem to work.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_about_logo);
    alert.setTitle("Phoebus Club");
    alert.setMessage("Please Insert Security Key");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        securityKey = input.getText().toString();
        if(securityKey == "oneplc"){
            System.exit(0);
        }
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Use String.#equals() method for comparing strings.

Comment: Thanks for you comment man!if(securityKey.equals("oneplc")){
            System.exit(0); did it for me!

Comment: just like this  securityKey.equals("onep1c");

Comment: @AndroidKrayze, not at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

[Have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

The `==` operator doesn't really compare values, rather reference equality. You should use the equals() method of the String object instead:

```
if(securityKey.equels("oneplc")){
     System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if static string then instead of

```
securityKey == "oneplc"
```

do

```
securityKey.equals("oneplc");
```

if from strings.xml then

```
securityKey.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.stringname));
```